# How to customize number of multiple hidden layer units in pytorch LSTM?

Tags: lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

In pytorch LSTM, RNN or GRU models, there is a parameter called "[num_layers](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#lstm)", which controls the number of hidden layers in an LSTM. I wonder that since there are multiple layers in an LSTM, why the parameter "hidden_size" is only one number instead of a list containing the number of hidden states in multiple layers, like [10, 20, 30].

I came across when I worked on a regression project, in which I feed sequence data of (seq_len, batch, feature) to LSTM, and I want to get the scalar output of every time step.

A helpful link to understand the pytorch LSTM framework, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48302810/whats-the-difference-between-hidden-and-output-in-pytorch-lstm).
I'd really appreciate it if anyone can answer this.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that I've found a solution to this, which is to use LSTMCell instead. Helpful links: [[1]](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/time_sequence_prediction/train.py), [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48187283/whats-the-difference-between-lstm-and-lstmcell). But is there an easier way?